# How to escape slashes in ruby string

Tags: ruby, string, backslash

I am getting a response from the params in a rhodes application, like this `"\"HOO123Wow\""`
But I need it, in a simple string format, like `"HOO123Wow"`. I have tried with `gsub` and `delete` but none of them seem to work for my application.

```
mystring = "\"HOO123Wow\""
mystring.gsub("\"", "")
```

Any suggestion will be really helpful.

Comment: The string you start with is actually `"HOO123Wow"`. Writing `mystring = '"HOO123Wow"'` creates exactly the same string. When my strings have any quotes, I prefer very much this notation: `mystring = %{"HOO123Wow"}`. `{}` are just one of many possible character pairs: `||`, `<>`, `()`, `[]` and many more.

Comment: What's wrong with `mystring.gsub("\"", "")`? It removes all quotes `"` in the string, returning only the alphanumeric characters. You can't strip the string any further than that.

Comment: Christoph's comment is valuable. Ruby's different string declaration formats serve these purposes. I tried `%{"H00123Wow"}.delete %{"}` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and elegant way:

```
string = "\"HOO123Wow\""
=> "\"HOO123Wow\""
string.tr('"','')
=> "HOO123Wow"
```

Done. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
irb(main)> eval mystring
=> "HOO123Wow"
```

or

```
irb(main)> mystring.delete ?"
=> "HOO123Wow"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `\\` for escaping slashes. Try this:

```
mystring = "\"HOO123Wow\"" 
mystring.gsub("\\\"", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

The value received in parameters == `"\"HOO123Wow\""`

Actual value to be persisted     == `"HOO123Wow"`

Here's what I did:

```
irb(main):001:0> mystring = "\"HOO123Wow\""
=> "\"HOO123Wow\""
irb(main):002:0> puts mystring.gsub("\\\"","")
"HOO123Wow"
=> nil
```

Hope it works for you.

**Note :**
I am using ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32]